# How to write a matrix update correctly with 'usestate'?

Tags: reactjs

I want there will be a matrix where a column with a '**name**' and a second column would be the '**Delete**' button. I defined '`usestate`' as an array and tried to insert values in it but it writes the following error:     "

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with
> keys {name, btn})
>
> . If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array
> instead."

```
 const [form,setform] = useState([{name:'',btn:''}]);
  
setform({...form,name:val, btn: (<button id={form.length} on onClick={()=>delet(form.length)}>delete</button>)});
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [form, setForm] = useState([
    { name: "Item1", btn: "Button1" },
    { name: "Item2", btn: "Button2" },
    { name: "Item3", btn: "Button3" },
    { name: "Item4", btn: "Button4" },
  ]);

  const deleteItemHandler = (name) => {
    setForm(form.filter((item) => item.name !== name));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {form.map((item) => (
        <div key={item.name}>
          <h3>{item.name}</h3>
          <button onClick={() => deleteItemHandler(item.name)}>
            Delete me
          </button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

And in this case you can remove `btn` from item object